# Как исправить ошибку во создания APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle, build

При запуске возникает ошибка

> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

вот её пояснение

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)

так выглядит guild.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'Shvedcom'
        keyPassword 'gfgefc'
        storeFile file('D:/IT/Android/Store_key/Shvedcom.jks')
        storePassword 'gfgefc'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shved.happycalendar"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
}

   dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1'
compile 'net.frakbot:jumpingbeans:1.3.0'
 }
```

Comment: Зря вы в открытый доступ ключ свой выложили

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас где-то переполняется массив.
Эта ошибка также может произойти, если путь к файлам проекта превышает 255 символов . Убедитесь, что ваш путь к проекту не слишком длинный, используйте короткие имена.
Также это может произойти при изменении XML файлов проекта. Попробуйте выполнить команду `Build > Rebuild Project`

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/86628)

Comment: Я исправлю, но автор дал только код build.gradle и описание ошибки, а этого явно не достаточно.

Comment: Александр, поле ответов служит только для конечных ответов на вопрос. Чтобы уточнить детали/подробности вопроса Вы можете воспользоваться комментариями под вопросом.

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает кнопка с комментариями под вопросом, на будущее учту.

Comment: У Вас недостаточно [репутации](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Для комментирования необходимо 50 баллов. P.S.: сейчас Ваш ответ стал лучше.

Comment: Замкнутый круг ;) Буду зарабатывать репутацию.